# Can you recommend a MediaWiki extension for visualizing the Wiki's links?

Tags: wiki, mediawiki, wikimedia

I'm preparing to launch a Wiki. Now, at the beginning, it is quite important for me to visualize how the the first pages I add are connected to each other. I found an extension called WikiViz that partially accomplishes what I am seeking. Here are a few images from Google Search:

https://www.google.com/#q=wikiviz&tbm=isch

Unfortunately this extension is no longer maintained and I doubt it plays nice with the newest version of MediaWiki.

Also, from what I can see, it uses a Java applet (very outdated). Or, it just generates images which aren't very useful: I'm trying to find an extension which actually uses Canvas & produces an interactive representation, at least with clickable links.

So, you Wiki gurus here, let the information flow :D.